# In Vue.js how to use multiple router-views one of which is inside another component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a Vue.js single page application where there is a main navbar that uses `<router-view/>` to render different pages.

Something like this:

```html
<main-header/> <!-- navigation links -->
<transition name="slide-fade" mode="out-in">
  <router-view/> <!-- different pages -->
</transition>
```

In one of those pages I have a sidebar that has more navigation links (that are using `<router-link/>` just like the main navbar.

Something like this:

```html
<sidebar/> <!-- navigation links -->
<div class="content">
  <transition name="slide-fade" mode="out-in">
    <router-view/> <!-- content beside the sidebar -->
  </transition>
</div>
```

When I click on the sidebar navigation links I want the content beside the sidebar to change as well as the url to change. However, I lose the sidebar, and just get the component that is to be rendered in the content section.

How do I achieve the desired result? How do I use multiple `<router-view/>`s one of which is inside another component, like the example above?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reason the sidebar disappeared is all the components are rendered in the first `<router-view>` besides the `<main-header>`.

You should use the nested router by configuring `children` in the sidebar router like:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/your-sidebar-url', component: your-sidebar-page,
      children: [
        {
          // A will be rendered in the second <router-view>
          // when /your-sidebar-url/a is matched
          path: 'a',
          component: A
        },
        {
          // B will be rendered in the second <router-view>
          // when /your-sidebar-url/b is matched
          path: 'b',
          component: B
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

More info in [nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html)

Answer (score 30):

You need to use `named views`. Provide the `name` attribute to the view.

```
<router-view class="view one"></router-view>
<router-view class="view two" name="a"></router-view>
```

And configure them like

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: {
        default: Foo,
        a: Bar
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Please refer to the [official docs](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html).

Comment: not working this

Comment: But why does it have eto be done this way? Why not just use the same view and have child routes still switch themselves back into the `<router-view />`

Answer (score 7):

@adoug answer helped me.

But in my case, I had named both router-view:

I did this to fix it:

```
<router-view name='a'/>
<router-view name='b'/>
```

You have , somewhere inside you `FatherComponent.vue` mounted in `a` you have a second

I did this, to fix it:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/your-sidebar-url',
            components: {
                a: FatherComponent //you sidebar main component in 'a' name of routed-view
            },
            children: [
                {
                    // A will be rendered in the second <router-view>
                    // when /your-sidebar-url/a is matched
                    path: '/child-path/a',
                    components: {
                        b: ChildComponentA //note that 'b' is the name of child router view
                    }
                },
                {
                    // B will be rendered in the second <router-view>
                    // when /your-sidebar-url/b is matched
                    path: '/child-path/b',
                    components: {
                        b: ChildComponentB //note that 'b' is the name of child router view
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks! The other answers were helpful but this one really cleared up my confusion

Comment: if childA or childB is calculated by JavaScript at runtime,  how to navigate via JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Named Route views

```js
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }
const Baz = { template: '<div>baz</div>' }

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/',
      // a single route can define multiple named components
      // which will be rendered into <router-view>s with corresponding names.
      components: {
        default: Foo,
        a: Bar,
        b: Baz
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/other',
      components: {
        default: Baz,
        a: Bar,
        b: Foo
      }
    }
  ]
})

new Vue({
    router,
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Named Views</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/">/</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/other">/other</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <router-view class="view one"></router-view>
  <router-view class="view two" name="a"></router-view>
  <router-view class="view three" name="b"></router-view>
</div>
```

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#nested-named-views