# How to build the "steps" component from PrimeVue in my Vue js app?

Tags: vue.js, primevue

When I use the code https://codesandbox.io/s/z7wzh I only get to see the image attached. How can I get the rest of the component to work in my Vue.js app? I don't know how to attach the components. I have made one called PersonalInformation.Vue and tried to change the "label" and "to" in the following code to call it

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Toast />

        <div class="card">
            <Steps :model="items" :readonly="true" />
        </div>

        <router-view v-slot="{Component}" :formData="formObject" @prevPage="prevPage($event)" @nextPage="nextPage($event)" @complete="complete">
            <keep-alive>
                <component :is="Component" />
            </keep-alive>
        </router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { useToast } from 'primevue/usetoast';
import PersonalInformation from './PersonalInformation.vue'

export default {
    setup() {
        const router = useRouter();
        const toast = useToast();
        const items = ref([
            {
                label: 'PersonalInformation',
                to: "/PersonalInformation"
            },
            {
                label: 'Seat',
                to: "/seat",
            },
            {
                label: 'Payment',
                to: "/payment",
            },
            {
                label: 'Confirmation',
                to: "/confirmation",
            }
        ]);
        const formObject = ref({});

        const nextPage = (event) => {
            for (let field in event.formData) {
                formObject.value[field] = event.formData[field];
            }

            router.push(items.value[event.pageIndex + 1].to);
        };
        const prevPage = (event) => {
            router.push(items.value[event.pageIndex - 1].to);
        };
        const complete = () => {
            toast.add({severity:'success', summary:'Order submitted', detail: 'Dear, ' + formObject.value.firstname + ' ' + formObject.value.lastname + ' your order completed.'});
        };

        return { items, formObject, nextPage, prevPage, complete }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
::v-deep(b) {
    display: block;
}

::v-deep(.p-card-body) {
    padding: 2rem;
}
</style>
```

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import Button from 'primevue/button'
import AutoComplete from 'primevue/autocomplete';
import Accordion from 'primevue/accordion';
import AccordionTab from 'primevue/accordiontab';
import Avatar from 'primevue/avatar';
import AvatarGroup from 'primevue/avatargroup';
import Badge from 'primevue/badge';
import BadgeDirective from "primevue/badgedirective";
import BlockUI from 'primevue/blockui';
import Breadcrumb from 'primevue/breadcrumb';
import Calendar from 'primevue/calendar';
import Card from 'primevue/card';
import CascadeSelect from 'primevue/cascadeselect';
import Carousel from 'primevue/carousel';
import Checkbox from 'primevue/checkbox';
import Chip from 'primevue/chip';
import Chips from 'primevue/chips';
import ColorPicker from 'primevue/colorpicker';
import Column from 'primevue/column';
import ColumnGroup from 'primevue/columngroup';
import ConfirmDialog from 'primevue/confirmdialog';
import ConfirmPopup from 'primevue/confirmpopup';
import ConfirmationService from 'primevue/confirmationservice';
import ContextMenu from 'primevue/contextmenu';
import DataTable from 'primevue/datatable';
import DataView from 'primevue/dataview';
import DataViewLayoutOptions from 'primevue/dataviewlayoutoptions';
import DeferredContent from 'primevue/deferredcontent';
import Dialog from 'primevue/dialog';
import Divider from 'primevue/divider';
import Dock from 'primevue/dock';
import Dropdown from 'primevue/dropdown';
import Fieldset from 'primevue/fieldset';
import FileUpload from 'primevue/fileupload';
import Galleria from 'primevue/galleria';
import Image from 'primevue/image';
import InlineMessage from 'primevue/inlinemessage';
import Inplace from 'primevue/inplace';
import InputSwitch from 'primevue/inputswitch';
import InputText from 'primevue/inputtext';
import InputMask from 'primevue/inputmask';
import InputNumber from 'primevue/inputnumber';
import Knob from 'primevue/knob';
import Listbox from 'primevue/listbox';
import MegaMenu from 'primevue/megamenu';
import Menu from 'primevue/menu';
import Menubar from 'primevue/menubar';
import Message from 'primevue/message';
import MultiSelect from 'primevue/multiselect';
import OrderList from 'primevue/orderlist';
import OrganizationChart from 'primevue/organizationchart';
import OverlayPanel from 'primevue/overlaypanel';
import Paginator from 'primevue/paginator';
import Panel from 'primevue/panel';
import PanelMenu from 'primevue/panelmenu';
import Password from 'primevue/password';
import PickList from 'primevue/picklist';
import ProgressBar from 'primevue/progressbar';
import ProgressSpinner from 'primevue/progressspinner';
import Rating from 'primevue/rating';
import RadioButton from 'primevue/radiobutton';
import Ripple from 'primevue/ripple';
import Row from 'primevue/row';
import SelectButton from 'primevue/selectbutton';
import ScrollPanel from 'primevue/scrollpanel';
import ScrollTop from 'primevue/scrolltop';
import Skeleton from 'primevue/skeleton';
import Slider from 'primevue/slider';
import Sidebar from 'primevue/sidebar';
import SpeedDial from 'primevue/speeddial';
import SplitButton from 'primevue/splitbutton';
import Splitter from 'primevue/splitter';
import SplitterPanel from 'primevue/splitterpanel';
import TabMenu from 'primevue/tabmenu';
import TieredMenu from 'primevue/tieredmenu';
import Textarea from 'primevue/textarea';
import Toast from 'primevue/toast';
import ToastService from 'primevue/toastservice';
import Toolbar from 'primevue/toolbar';
import TabView from 'primevue/tabview';
import TabPanel from 'primevue/tabpanel';
import Tag from 'primevue/tag';
import Terminal from 'primevue/terminal';
import Timeline from 'primevue/timeline';
import ToggleButton from 'primevue/togglebutton';
import Tooltip from 'primevue/tooltip';
import Tree from 'primevue/tree';
import TreeSelect from 'primevue/treeselect';
import TreeTable from 'primevue/treetable';
import TriStateCheckbox from 'primevue/tristatecheckbox';
import VirtualScroller from 'primevue/virtualscroller';
import Steps from 'primevue/steps';
import 'primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css'       //theme
import 'primevue/resources/primevue.min.css'                 //core css
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css'

//global styles
import './assets/main.css'

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(PrimeVue);
app.use(ConfirmationService);
app.use(ToastService);

app.component('Steps', Steps);
app.component('Button', Button);
app.component('Accordion', Accordion);
app.component('AccordionTab', AccordionTab);
app.component('AutoComplete', AutoComplete);
app.component('Avatar', Avatar);
app.component('AvatarGroup', AvatarGroup);
app.component('Badge', Badge);
app.component('BlockUI', BlockUI);
app.component('Breadcrumb', Breadcrumb);
app.component('Button', Button);
app.component('Calendar', Calendar);
app.component('Card', Card);
app.component('Carousel', Carousel);
app.component('CascadeSelect', CascadeSelect);
app.component('Checkbox', Checkbox);
app.component('Chip', Chip);
app.component('Chips', Chips);
app.component('ColorPicker', ColorPicker);
app.component('Column', Column);
app.component('ColumnGroup', ColumnGroup);
app.component('ConfirmDialog', ConfirmDialog);
app.component('ConfirmPopup', ConfirmPopup);
app.component('ContextMenu', ContextMenu);
app.component('DataTable', DataTable);
app.component('DataView', DataView);
app.component('DataViewLayoutOptions', DataViewLayoutOptions);
app.component('DeferredContent', DeferredContent);
app.component('Dialog', Dialog);
app.component('Divider', Divider);
app.component('Dock', Dock);
app.component('Dropdown', Dropdown);
app.component('Fieldset', Fieldset);
app.component('FileUpload', FileUpload);
app.component('Galleria', Galleria);
app.component('Image', Image);
app.component('InlineMessage', InlineMessage);
app.component('Inplace', Inplace);
app.component('InputMask', InputMask);
app.component('InputNumber', InputNumber);
app.component('InputSwitch', InputSwitch);
app.component('InputText', InputText);
app.component('Knob', Knob);
app.component('Listbox', Listbox);
app.component('MegaMenu', MegaMenu);
app.component('Menu', Menu);
app.component('Menubar', Menubar);
app.component('Message', Message);
app.component('MultiSelect', MultiSelect);
app.component('OrderList', OrderList);
app.component('OrganizationChart', OrganizationChart);
app.component('OverlayPanel', OverlayPanel);
app.component('Paginator', Paginator);
app.component('Panel', Panel);
app.component('PanelMenu', PanelMenu);
app.component('Password', Password);
app.component('PickList', PickList);
app.component('ProgressBar', ProgressBar);
app.component('ProgressSpinner', ProgressSpinner);
app.component('RadioButton', RadioButton);
app.component('Rating', Rating);
app.component('Row', Row);
app.component('SelectButton', SelectButton);
app.component('ScrollPanel', ScrollPanel);
app.component('ScrollTop', ScrollTop);
app.component('Slider', Slider);
app.component('Sidebar', Sidebar);
app.component('Skeleton', Skeleton);
app.component('SpeedDial', SpeedDial);
app.component('SplitButton', SplitButton);
app.component('Splitter', Splitter);
app.component('SplitterPanel', SplitterPanel);
app.component('Steps', Steps);
app.component('TabMenu', TabMenu);
app.component('TabView', TabView);
app.component('TabPanel', TabPanel);
app.component('Tag', Tag);
app.component('Textarea', Textarea);
app.component('Terminal', Terminal);
app.component('TieredMenu', TieredMenu);
app.component('Timeline', Timeline);
app.component('Toast', Toast);
app.component('Toolbar', Toolbar);
app.component('ToggleButton', ToggleButton);
app.component('Tree', Tree);
app.component('TreeSelect', TreeSelect);
app.component('TreeTable', TreeTable);
app.component('TriStateCheckbox', TriStateCheckbox);
app.component('VirtualScroller', VirtualScroller)
app.use(router);
app.mount('#app');
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you installed the required dependencies?

Comment: Do you see any error on the console?

Comment: No errors as such but there's a warning in yellow saying ```failed to resolve component v-main``` and as for dependencies I simply went into the main js file and copied all the components being imported. Is there any other dependencies you are referring to?

Comment: Hi! I would really appreciate your help. Here's the repository https://github.com/Bilolhussain/UserVue

Comment: @Amaarrockz can you please help? You said you would be able to implement the changes if I shared the repository.

Comment: You need to use nested routes as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111573/in-vue-js-how-to-use-multiple-router-views-one-of-which-is-inside-another-compon